# Python call() method yields java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I am new to the subprocess package in Python. I am trying to use the call() method from that package to send the following command to the terminal:

> C:\mallet-2.0.7\bin\mallet import-dir --input
>   C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory --output tutorial.mallet
>   --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords

I have attempted to use the following bit of Python code to accomplish this task:

```
import os
from subprocess import call

class Mallet(object):
    def __init__(self, input_path, mallet_path, topics):
        self.mallet_exec = os.path.abspath('C:\\mallet-2.0.7\\bin\\mallet')
        self.input_path = os.path.abspath('C:\\mallet-2.0.7\\inputdirectory')
        self.topics = '14'

    def import_dir(self):
        text_path = self.input_path 
        output = os.path.abspath('C:\\mallet-2.0.7\\inputdirectory')
        call(self.mallet_exec + " import-dir --input " + input_path + " --keep-sequence --output " + output, shell=True)

input_path = os.path.abspath('C:\\mallet-2.0.7\\inputdirectory')
mallet_path = os.path.abspath('C:\\mallet-2.0.7')
output = 'tutorial.mallet'
topics = '14'

malletfunction = Mallet(input_path, mallet_path, topics)
malletfunction.import_dir()
```

When I run the above code, however, I get the following error message:

> Labels =     C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory Exception in thread "main"
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory (Access
>   is denied)    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors.main(Text2Vectors.java:320)

Does anyone know how I might resolve this error? I would be most grateful for any light others can shed on this question.

(In case it might help, I'm working in Windows 8, with Python 2.7.5)

```
################
# EDITED CODE: #
################

import os
from subprocess import call

class Mallet(object):
    def __init__(self, input_path, mallet_path = 'C:\\mallet-2.0.7'):
        self.mallet_exec = mallet_path + "\\bin\\mallet"
        self.input_path = 'C:\\mallet-2.0.7\\inputdirectory'

    def import_dir(self):
        text_path = self.input_path 
        output = "preparedforinput.mallet"
        call(self.mallet_exec + " import-dir --input " + input_path + " --keep-sequence --output " + output , shell=True)

input_path = 'C:\\mallet-2.0.7\\inputdirectory'
mallet_path = 'C:\\mallet-2.0.7'

malletfunction = Mallet(input_path, mallet_path)
malletfunction.import_dir()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `abspath` on literals that are already absolute paths? Are you expecting to get back something different? If so, what?

Comment: Meanwhile: Does the command line shown at the top actually work from the DOS prompt? Why are you trying to generate a different command line in `subprocess.call` than what you use at the DOS prompt? If you `print` the command line instead of `call`ing it, and then paste it into the DOS prompt, does it work? What happens if, in a DOS prompt, you `dir C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory\foo` and then `type` one of the files in it? Are you running the script from the same working directory that you run the command from in the DOS prompt?

Comment: Thank you, @abarnert, these are helpful questions. The abspath() may well be unnecessary; I'll cut them and just give the literal file paths. (I was using them because Windows seems to treat certain parts of file paths as regular expressions on occassion.) As for the command, it works, but only if it is issued from the C:\mallet-2.0.7 directory. That is to say, so far as I can tell, I need to be in C:\mallet-2.0.7 and then I need to issue the desired command for it to work.

Comment: Windows never treats any parts of a path as a regular expression. In fact, Windows has very little support for regexes at all (except in .NET and higher-level APIs).

Comment: I misspoke--I should have said, working in Python within a Windows environment, I sometimes find that Python converts a path name like "C:\mallet\bin" into something that is not equal to "C:\mallet\\bin." (It seems \b and so forth are reserved characters, not regex? This may well be the case in other os environments as well.) In any event, I've found that using two slashes in file paths makes those paths behave as I would like them to.

Comment: It's not Windows doing that, but Python. In a regular string, `'\b'` turns into a backspace, `'\n'` into a newline, `'\1'` into a control-A, etc. You can handle this by escaping your backslashes, but a much better solution is to use raw strings: `r'C:\blah\monkey\1'`.

Comment: Thank you, @abarnert, I'll try the raw strings method. I truly appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really given us enough information to be sure, but your Python code is clearly not running the same command line you're using at the DOS prompt, and one of the differences seems very suspicious.

Presumably this works:

> C:\mallet-2.0.7\bin\mallet import-dir --input C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory --output tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords

But what Python is generating is:

> C:\mallet-2.0.7\bin\mallet import-dir --input C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory --keep-sequence --output C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory

Notice the difference in the `--output` parameter? In the DOS prompt, you're asking `mallet` to write its output to a file or directory at the relative path `tutorial.mallet`. In Python, you're asking it to write its output to `C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory`.

Presumably, either you don't have write permission to `C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory`, or `mallet` wants to write a file, not a directory, and it can't create a file named `C:\mallet-2.0.7\inputdirectory` because there's already a directory there.

Comment: Thank you, @abarnert, for your help. I believe I have fixed the output parameter, and am running the Python script from the C:\mallet-2.0.7 directory. Although I am not receiving any error message, I am also not finding any output. I will post my edited code above. If you see anything else that you think needs correction, I would be most grateful for any advice you can lend.

Comment: Ah, you've fixed it @abarnert! Thank you! (It took me longer than it should have to realize that mallet was creating output in an unexpected directory.) Thank you so much for helping me to resolve this question!